# Workflow Manager / Service Bus 1.1 How do I configure SB Portal?

Tags: powershell, servicebus, workflow-manager-1.x, azure-pack

I have a testserver with Windows Azure Pack, Workflow Manger and Service Bus 1.1

Installing Workflow manager and configureing it I had to remove old SB databases to replace them through the workflow configuration wizard.

When this is done there is a problem, in the wizard there were no option to configure the service portal and AdminApiUsername & TenantApiUserName.

I can't find how to fix this through powershell or anything else when the wizard is done?

Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

Stop-SBFarm
$RPAdminPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force ''

$SBRPAdminCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'SBRPAdminUser',$RPAdminPassword

$RPTenantPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force ''

$SBRPTenantCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 'SBRPTenantUser',$RPTenantPassword

Set-SBFarm -AdminApiCredentials $SBRPAdminCredentials -TenantApiCredentials $SBRPTenantCredentials

[RunOnAllNodes] Update-SBHost

Start-SBFarm

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn520958.aspx

Comment: I found this 1 day after I posted. Just forgot for some stupid reason to add it here.